# how to set selected value in php?

Tags: php

i make a php page in which i post data i want when post data is equal to option value then option value show selected,here is my post data:

```
Array (
    [events]       => Array 
    [fromdate]     => February 12, 2014 3:10 PM 
    [todate]       => February 19, 2014 3:10 PM 
    [description]  => hfhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh 
    [subject]      => fhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh 
    [fromname]     => gjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj 
    [replyto]      => gjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj 
    [senddatetime] => February 12, 2014 3:10 PM 
    [timezone]     => America/Los_Angeles 
    [message]      =>

                 dhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    [submit_skip]  => Continue 
)
```

and here is my code:

```
        $select = sprintf ("SELECT event_id,event_name
                              FROM `events`
                              WHERE (`user_id` = '%s') order by event_name",
                            $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->real_escape_string ($_SESSION['user_id']));

        $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        if ($res->num_rows > 0)
        {                   
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc ())
            {
                foreach( $_POST['events'] as $val ){ ?>

                     <option value="<?= $row['event_id']; 
                         if($row['event_id'] == $val) echo "selected";
                     ?>">
                         <?=$row['event_name']?>
                     </option>

                     <?
                 }
             }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
```

i want [events] => Array checked in select option and if events value matched select box show selected,how i do this?

when i run this error show:

```
Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\ticket_inspector_new\forms_hd87wblfo084wgdtry\form_email_compose
```

Comment: Using `short_tags` is discouraged BTW, as XML declarations also start with `<?` and lead to PHP syntax errors if present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create events array separately, then apply this, like this

```
    <?php
    $x = array (
        'events'       => array(), 
        'fromdate'     => 'February 12, 2014 3:10 PM', 
        'todate'       => 'February 19, 2014 3:10 PM', 
       // So on .....
    ); 

    $check = $x['events'];

    var_dump($check);

    ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>"<?php if(in_array($row['event_id'],$check)) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> ><?php echo $row['event_name']?></option>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Did you get an error message? Or just no the output you intended (and if so - what did you get and what did you expect)?

Comment: are you getting values in $check array?

Comment: So that's your problem, first of all, make separate array with which you want to compare, like $events. then put that array name in_array() condition. ur problem will be sort out